# unsupported_grant_type error when I try to authenticate a user

Tags: angular, laravel, typescript, laravel-passport

I know that there has been a lot of questions and answers about what I am going to ask but none of them has solved my problem.

Now, I am developing an angular 5 application and I am trying to get an authentication token by sending post to a server. When I use postman to test the connections there is no problem. But in angular I get the following error

[image: 400 (Bad Request) "unsupported_grant_type"]

Here is what I wrote so far,

```
getAccessToken2() {
let url = "http://api.akilli.tv/oauth/token";

var headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

let urlSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
urlSearchParams.set('grant_type', 'password');
urlSearchParams.set('username', 'alikamilyagli@gmail.com');
urlSearchParams.set('password', '1234');
urlSearchParams.set('client_id', '2');
urlSearchParams.set('client_secret', 'Q5U9fclient*!secret*!clientsecret*!9SqUaH9sKro');
urlSearchParams.set('scope', '*');

let body = urlSearchParams.toString();

return this.http.post(url, body)
  .subscribe((data: any) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

}

And here is a screenshot of postman request which was succesfull
[image]

And I have also faced with the  Access-allow-control-origin problem and solved by adding a chrome add-on which is called "CORS". Is there another and healthier way of solving this?

Thanks in advance already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
const data = 'grant_type=password';
        return this.http.post( url, data,
            {headers: new HttpHeaders({'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'})});
```

Comment: what you typed has syntax error still trying to fix it

Comment: you have to edit your code because it has a syntax error. It really worked all I changed was the post method 3rd parameter just like you showed. I couldnt't figure out how that changes everything but it really did.